# Python - blender XML annotation files (doesnt work with matlab code)

Tags: python, xml, matlab

I have used blender-python to create an XML file(annotation) ,but the problem is when I use it with a Matlab code to read it, it gives me the following error:

```
Error in VOCxml2struct>parse (line 10)
if ~isempty(parent)&&xml(ind)~='<'
```

**from this function** :

```
res=[];

if ~isempty(parent)&&xml(ind)~='<'

i=findchar(xml,ind,'<');

res=trim(xml(ind:i-1));

ind=i;

[tag,ind]=gettag(xml,i);

if ~strcmp(tag,['/' parent])

    error('<%s> closed with <%s>',parent,tag);
end
```

it's a bit confusing given that XML files from Pascal_Voc data set do work fine with the same code and when you see both XML files they look identical, I have created the required tags manually and below is my blender-python code, hopefully, there is a suggestion for me to fix it.

Thank you all for your time.

```
with open("000007.xml", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  file.write ("<annotation>\n")
  file.write (" <folder>VOC2007</folder>\n")
  file.write (" <filename>" + '000007.jpg' + "</filename>\n")
  file.write (" <source>\n")
  file.write ("     <database>The VOC2007 Database</database>\n")
  file.write ("     <annotation>PASCAL VOC2007</annotation>\n")
  file.write ("     <image>flickr</image>\n")
  file.write ("     <flickrid>194179466</flickrid>\n")
  file.write (" </source>\n")
  file.write (" <owner>\n")
  file.write ("     <flickrid>monsieurrompu</flickrid>\n")
  file.write ("     <name>Thom Zemanek</name>\n")
  file.write (" </owner>\n")
  file.write (" </size>\n")
  file.write ("     <width>500</width>\n")
  file.write ("     <height>333</height>\n")
  file.write ("     <depth>3</depth>\n")
  file.write (" </size>\n")
  file.write (" <segmented>0</segmented>\n")
  file.write (" <object>\n")
  file.write ("     <name>car</name>\n")
  file.write ("     <pose>Unspecified</pose>\n")
  file.write ("     <truncated>1</truncated>\n")
  file.write ("     <difficult>0</difficult>\n")
  file.write ("     <bndbox>")
  file.write ("\n           <xmin>" + '141' + "</xmin>")
  file.write ("\n           <ymin>" + '50' + "</ymin>")
  file.write ("\n           <xmax>" + '500' + "</xmax>")
  file.write ("\n           <ymax>" + '330' + "</ymax>")
  file.write ("\n       </bndbox>\n")
  file.write (" </object>\n")
  file.write ("</annotation>\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question** ... when you see both XML files they look identical

**Don't** Trust your **eyes** use a `diff` Programm to compare!
Use a XML Validator like [xmlvalidation.com](https://xmlvalidation.com/)

Didn't know if it's related to `Matlab` Error but your code and therfore the resulting `XML` have the following Error:

```
# Missing Header
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

# First has to be <size> not closing
file.write (" </size>\n")
```

Think about using a `xml` Python Module to Create `XML`.